# PyTorch can't find the name?? (NameError: name 'device' is not defined)

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, device

#### sorry - I'm a complete beginner!

I am trying to build a 'mini-system' using the Torchreid libraries from https://kaiyangzhou.github.io/deep-person-reid/index.html#

In their version they use CUDA but my Mac is not compatible with CUDA and it doesn't have a
CUDA enabled GPU so I installed the CPU-only version of PyTorch instead - therefore I changed `model = model.cuda()` to `model = model.to(device)` and added in `device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')` as you can see below. I thought this would work but I keep getting the `NameError: name 'device' is not defined` and I don't know what to do.
Please help!

(I also tried putting `device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')` at the top instead of the bottom to see if it made any difference but I just got another error - `NameError: name 'torch' is not defined`)

```
model = torchreid.models.build_model(
    name='resnet50',
    num_classes=datamanager.num_train_pids,
    loss='softmax',
    pretrained=True
)

model = model.to(device)

optimizer = torchreid.optim.build_optimizer(
    model,
    optim='adam',
    lr=0.0003
)

scheduler = torchreid.optim.build_lr_scheduler(
    optimizer,
    lr_scheduler='single_step',
    stepsize=20
)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

Answer (score 5):

Define `device` variable before the usage:

```py
import torch
...
model = torchreid.models.build_model(
    name='resnet50',
    num_classes=datamanager.num_train_pids,
    loss='softmax',
    pretrained=True
)

# Just right before the actual usage
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = model.to(device)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the torch module.

Put

```
import torch
```

at the top of the code.

(And remember always import the libraries you're using)